# Раcкодировка &amp;

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, имеется массив,
куда через `php` вставляется ссылка

```
/velosiped-stark-router-2013-p-129823.html?action=ADD2BASKET&id=121578&amp%3Bid=121576
```

а при выведении на экран этой ссылки, вместо & вставляется &amp;
вот так:

```
/velosiped-stark-router-2013-p-129823.html?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=121578&amp;amp%3Bid=121576
```

Почему так происходит и как это убрать?
массив находится на странице в теге `<script></script>`

Comment: Вот этого я честно сказать не знаю, так как не программист, а как можно избежать этого

Comment: Вы были правы все из-за htmlspecialchars, спасибо!! Напишите свой комментарий как ответ, я его отмечу как правельный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже у вас при выводе из php используется htmlspecialchars (?)